# Edit Joomla Module CSS

Tags: html, css, joomla

So, this entire area is JhotelResrvation Module. I figured out where the module files are but unfortunately I cannot edit the CSS to effect changes, doesn't seem to work on the custom CSS also. I would've initially written a code to set some padding to the dark-transparent box.

```
div.mod_hotel_reservation.horizontal {
    padding-left: 55px;
}
```

This doesn't seem to effect any changes. Please view image below [Experience Beautiful Ghana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK3qO.png)

Website URL https://gta.stillwaters.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't work beacuse that div already has a padding:

```
.mod_hotel_reservation.horizontal {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    padding: 10px 0 !important; //this one
}
```

So if you want the `padding-left: 55px;` to work you have to delete the `padding: 10px 0 !important;`.

If your css changes don't show up on your browser, have you tried to clear the cache for the website? You just have to press `F12` key to enter developer tools when you are on your website. Then right click on the refresh button on the top left and click `Empty cache and Hard reload`.

Comment: can you located the css file from your end?

Comment: The path where you can find that file is `https://gta.stillwaters.io/modules/mod_jhotelreservation/assets/jhotelreservationGeneral.css`. Access to your website via FTP and follow that path. There you can change the CSS rules.

Comment: Thank you. Can you share what plugin you used to get this info?

Comment: There is no plugin needed, you just press F12 in Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox and there you can use developer tools. You can see in the Elements tab, your page in html. Browse to the element you want to inspect and then click on it. On the right side you can see the css codeand for each section the name of the file where that code is. Hover the mouse and you can see the complete path.